# Windows 10 Registry SubKey REG_MULTI_SZ How do I edit just some of the values

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-10, registry

Good Morning,

I could use help, I'm trying to edit just some of the values of a REG_MULTI_SZ using PowerShell but I'm not having any luck.

The Key is:  `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Bentley\BentleyDesktopClient\Install`

[image]

And the original value of the key is:

```
KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=
KeyName_CheckUpdateOptionModTime=<number-varies>
KeyName_UpdateClientInstallTime=<number-varies>
KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=1
```

(depending on the install, the values `KeyName_CheckUpdateOptionModTime=<some-number>` and `KeyName_UpdateClientInstallTime=<some-number>` will be different.)

I want the end result after editing to be:

```
KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=3
KeyName_CheckUpdateOptionModTime=<number-varies>
KeyName_UpdateClientInstallTime=<number-varies>
KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=0
```

But the best I've been able to come up with is replacing all the data with just one line with this script:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Bentley\BentleyDesktopClient\Install /t REG_MULTI_SZ /v "UpdateClient" /d "Keyname_CheckUpdateOption=3"
```

So the result I get is:

[image]

So the question is, how can I replace just SOME of the values in a Multi-String key, and preserve the rest and their order?

I would like to then create a Batch file so I can run this on multiple pc's.

I really appreciate everyone's time and assistance, Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be too much code lines of powershell, but it works for me:

```
Clear-Host
$currentProperty = (Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Bentley\BentleyDesktopClient\Install | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "UpdateClient")
#You may need this to compare in the future
$newProperty = $currentProperty

#Searching value KeyName_CheckUpdateOption. If value set - replace it, if not - set it
$CurrentKeyName_CheckUpdateOption = $null
$CurrentKeyName_CheckUpdateOption = ($newProperty | Select-String -Pattern 'KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=([0-9.]+)')
if($CurrentKeyName_CheckUpdateOption.Matches.Value) {
    Write-Output $CurrentKeyName_CheckUpdateOption.Matches.Value
    $newProperty = $newProperty.Replace("$($CurrentKeyName_CheckUpdateOption.Matches.Value)","KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=3")
} else {
    $newProperty = $newProperty.Replace("KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=","KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=3")
}

#Same for KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled.
$CurrentKeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled = $null
$CurrentKeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled = ($newProperty | Select-String -Pattern 'KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=([0-9.]+)')
if($CurrentKeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled.Matches.Value) {
    $newProperty = $newProperty.Replace("$($CurrentKeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled.Matches.Value)","KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=0")
} else {
    $newProperty = $newProperty.Replace("KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=","KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=0")
}

# Set updated value to registry
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Bentley\BentleyDesktopClient\Install -Name UpdateClient -Value $newProperty
```

Comment: Thank you Alex R. Very Very Much.  I have a question for you if I may.  During my search for answers to my issue I ran across other posts where folks suggested looking in the 'Reg /?' Help files but I didn't see these commands you used.  The language you used is PowerShell correct?  Can you recommend any book on PowerShell and or Batch file creation or perhaps some Udemy class?  Thanks!

Comment: @Grot yes, this is powershell. I can recommend you to visit official powershell documentation site https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/. You can find here lots of examples.

Comment: One last question please @Alex R. what do you recommend is the best way to automate this script?  If I want to run this script on multiple pc's would you recommend saving this PowerShell script as a ps1 file and then run it from a BAT file or would you recommend some other way?

Comment: @Grot If you are using Domain you can use `Invoke-Command -ComputerName "COMPUTERNAME" -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock { put here code }`. This is the best and fastest method.

Comment: Thanks Again.  Hope you had a good Fourth, Peace Out!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `switch` for this like below:

```
$regPath  = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Bentley\BentleyDesktopClient\Install'
$oldValue = (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regPath -Name 'UpdateClient') -ne ''
$newValue = switch -Wildcard ($oldValue) {
    'KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=*'    { 'KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=3' }
    'KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=*' { 'KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=0' }
    default { $_ }  # return this item unchanged
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name 'UpdateClient' -Value $newValue
```

The new content of the registry value will be:

```
KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=3
KeyName_CheckUpdateOptionModTime=<number-varies>
KeyName_UpdateClientInstallTime=<number-varies>
KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=0
```

Comment: This will not work, cause you losing rest of the lines of UpdateClient key

Comment: @AlexR. Nope, you can try yourself. It won't loose anything, because lines that do not match will be output unchanged because of `default { $_ }`. I have added the output and for your info a comment after the default line

Comment: Magnificent! I've never thought that switch can be used like that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Theo, that looks neat and tidy - Cool.  PowerShell is new to me, do you have any recommendations for PowerShell books or online training?

Comment: @Grot Well, just google for PowerShell tutorials or training, There is lots to be found like [this](https://www.guru99.com/powershell-tutorial.html) or [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/introduction-to-powershell/) or [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/index.htm) for instance

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag, here's something which does not use `powershell.exe`, and which still uses your used `reg.exe` utility.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "MultiStr="
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Bentley\BentleyDesktopClient\Install" /V "UpdateClient" 2^>NUL') Do Set "MultiStr=%%H" 
If Not Defined MultiStr GoTo :EOF
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set _Item[) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "i=1"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_Item[%i%]=%MultiStr:\0=" & Set /A i += 1 & Set "_Item[!i!]=%"
Set "MultiStr="
If Not Defined _Item[1] (EndLocal & GoTo :EOF)
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set _Item[) 2>NUL"') Do If "%%H" == "KeyName_CheckUpdateOption" (If /I Not "%%I" == "3" Set "%%G=%%H=3") Else If "%%H" == "KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled" If /I Not "%%I" == "0" Set "%%G=%%H=0"
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set _Item[) 2>NUL"') Do If Not Defined MultiStr (Set "MultiStr=%%H") Else Set "MultiStr=!MultiStr!\0%%H"
If Not Defined MultiStr (EndLocal & GoTo :EOF)
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Bentley\BentleyDesktopClient\Install" /V "UpdateClient" /T REG_MULTI_SZ /D "!MultiStr!" /F 1>NUL
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

The basic idea is that it reads the registry value data, separates it into list items, checks each list item for the key pairs, adjusting as necessary, rebuilds the data, and adds it back to the registry.

*Please note that as this is modifying a Local Machine Key, it will need to be 'Run as administrator'/elevated.*

*Caveat: this script will only maintain the multi-string item order if there are nine items or less*

Comment: Hello @Compo, so if what you produced isn't PowerShell what is it then?  Can I paste your code in a txt file and then rename the file extension to something and run it?  I can run it as a series of commands at the cmd line, but I'm not sure how to run it as a file?

Comment: @Grot, I made it clear that my answer was relative to your [[tag:batch-file]] tag. It is therefore a batch file, which should have a `.cmd` extension, although those who have not yet moved into the twenty first century could use `.bat` instead. To run it, right-click on it and select 'Run as administrator'. TBF, if you didn't know what a batch file was, or how to run one, you shouldn't have tagged your question with [[tag:batch-file]].

Answer (score 0):

@Theo, thanks.
I modified the script to disable other annoying options of the Bentley Connection Client.

```
$regPath  = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Bentley\BentleyDesktopClient\Install'
$oldValue = (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regPath -Name 'UpdateClient') -ne ''
$newValue = switch -Wildcard ($oldValue) {
    'KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=*'    { 'KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=3' }
    'KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=*' { 'KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=0' }
    default { $_ }  # return this item unchanged
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name 'UpdateClient' -Value $newValue

New-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name 'AutoLogin' -PropertyType String -Value 'False' -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name 'OnboardingShown' -PropertyType String -Value 'True' -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name 'ShowDesktopNotifications' -PropertyType String -Value 'False' -Force

$regPath  = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
Remove-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name 'Bentley License Service' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Morning MassStorage, Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

Here's two different ways to do the same in powershell.

```
#Declare the variables and retrieve the data from the registry
$Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Bentley\BentleyDesktopClient\Install"
$Value = "UpdateClient"
$NewUpdateOptionValue = 4
$NewUpdateEnabledValue = 0

$ValueData = Get-ItemPropertyValue $key -Name $Value
```

Since `$ValueData` will be an array of strings, you can loop through them using a for loop. In that loop you can inspect each item and decide if you want to update. Using Regex here also lets you pull out the existing value of the string, by looking for 0 or more (*) digits (\d):

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ValueData.Count; $i++) {
    if ($ValueData[$i] -imatch "KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=(\d*)") { 
        $ValueData[$i] = "KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=" + $NewUpdateOptionValue
        Write-Host "Old value was " $matches[1] 
    }
    if ($ValueData[$i] -imatch "KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=(\d*)") { 
        $ValueData[$i] = "KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=" + $NewUpdateEnabledValue
        Write-Host "Old value was " $matches[1] 
    }
}
```

Another way is to use the switch option with Regex. This also loops through each of the entries, looking for matches to update, or just return everything else with `default`. This is written back into the same variable:

```
 switch -Regex ($ValueData) {
    "KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=(\d*)" {
        Write-Output ("KeyName_CheckUpdateOption=" + $NewUpdateOptionValue)
        Write-Host "Old value was " $matches[1] 
    }
    "KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=(\d*)" {
        Write-Output ("KeyName_CheckUpdateIsEnabled=" + $NewUpdateEnabledValue)
        Write-Host "Old value was " $matches[1] 
    }
    default { Write-Output $_ }
}
```

Note that the explicit Write-Output sends the data back into the variable while Write-Host sends it to the console. Just running that block on its own (without the `$ValueData =`) will print both in sequence onto the console.

Finally, write the updated contents back to the registry:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $Key -Name $Value -Value $ValueData
```